# Static admin page for all multisite users

Tags: customization, multisite, admin-bar

I want to have a stats page that all my multisite users can see, it'll give info on the network like number of users, number of posts, number of blogs, some graphs, etc.

In the admin bar, i've created a dropdown for my multisite with an option for stats (I'll eventually expand this later on). I created it using the `$admin_bar->add_node()` function, which asks me to specify an href for the pages. These pages do not currently exist and for the life how me I cannot figure out how to make them exist.

I'm wanting this new page to be apart of the wp_admin for the network that is publicly available to everyone. Worst case I'll have to end up making it apart of my main networks blog, but I would really rather avoid that.

I've been struggling with this for hours and would really appreciate some guidance.